# Why won't my log in user GUI set the warning label correctly?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing a simple user log in screen that will store users through serialization. The GUI is fine, and all that's really left is to implement serialization, but I can't get my `warningLabel` to display text correctly when a user inputs an incorrect password or username. It will display the first error message, but if a different error occurs, the label stays the same. I need the label to change EVERY TIME there is an error. I'll post the whole code below.

UserCreateAccountGUI class:

```
package userInfoAndSerialization;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class UserCreateAccount implements ActionListener {

    public static int numOfUsers;

    String username;
    String password;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        UserCreateAccount ucaGUI = new UserCreateAccount();
        ucaGUI.start();
    }

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField usernameField;
    JPasswordField passwordField;
    JPasswordField confirmPasswordField;
    JLabel warningLabel;

    public void start() {
        frame = new JFrame("Create a new account");
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        JLabel confirmPasswordLabel = new JLabel("Confirm Password:");
        usernameField = new JTextField(15);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(15);
        confirmPasswordField = new JPasswordField(15);

        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

        right.weightx = (int) 2;
        right.fill = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        right.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        // actual GUI

        panel.add(userLabel, left);
        panel.add(usernameField, right);
        panel.add(passwordLabel, left);
        panel.add(passwordField, right);
        panel.add(confirmPasswordLabel, left);
        panel.add(confirmPasswordField, right);

        frame.setSize(300, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton createAccount = new JButton("Create this account");
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, createAccount);
        createAccount.addActionListener(this);

        warningLabel = new JLabel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, warningLabel);
    }

    // this is where the problem is.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (!(passwordField.getPassword().toString().equals(confirmPasswordField.getPassword().toString()))) {
            warningLabel.setText("Your passwords do not match! Please try again!");
        } else if (passwordField.getPassword().toString().length() < 1 ) {
            warningLabel.setText("Your password is not long enough! Please try again!");
        } else if (usernameField.getText().length() < 1) {
            warningLabel.setText("Your username is not long enough! Please try again!");
        } else {
            warningLabel.setText("Account created successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to fly:

```
passwordField.getPassword().toString().
       equals(confirmPasswordField.getPassword().toString())
```

You'd better print out the results of calling `.toString()` on a char array to see exactly what I mean.

For instance, when I run:

```
String fooString = "Foo";
char[] fooArray = fooString.toCharArray();
System.out.println(fooArray.toString());
```

It does not return "Foo" as you seem to be expecting, but rather the typical and expected `toString()` representation of a char array: `[C@19821f`. Note that if you run this, your hashcode number will be different from mine (same if I run this a second time!).

Better to use the Arrays class `equals(...)` method to let you compare the two char arrays. i.e.,

```
char[] pw1 = passwordField.getPassword();
char[] pw2 = confirmPasswordField.getPassword();
if (Arrays.equals(pw1, pw2)) {
   //...
}
```

Note: a bad solution would be to translate the char arrays into a "real" String using `new String(myCharArray)`, but I strongly advise against doing this as it makes your passwords very weak and easy to break.

Comment: @Hovecraftfullofeels What if I need these passwords to be saved later for serialization? I need to be able to turn them into something that is representable for user log in? How should I do this?

Comment: @HashSlingingHacker: You shouldn't save passwords for serialization. I'm no expert on security, but this just worries me. One sort of kludge I suppose would be to save a password's hashcode, but even that worries me.

Comment: @Hovecraftfullofeels I'm not saving passwords, I'm saving User accounts, as in objects. These user accounts will hold other variables like balance, along with methods. If I was just saving passwords/usernames, I'd just save them to a text file, but since these User objects have other things associated with them, those are the things that will be serialized.

Comment: @HashSlingingHacker: but if the password is stored in the user accounts, then it's easily hacked.

Comment: @Hovecraftfullofeels I really don't know anything about hacking. How would somebody be able to get into these? Doesn't serialization stop that from happening by converting all of the information into bytecode during deserialization?